# Boolean and armature

Tags: boolean-modifier

I wanted to print a drawing I had made, but first I wanted to create a pedestal to make it stand upright.
I was making holes in the drawing but when I do boolean it doesn't work as well as it should and creates a weird thing for me.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmv87.png)
I think the problem might be the armature but I don't know how to fix it. Applying to the armature changes the shape of my feet slightly (in my original drawing I have shoes so I notice it well). What can I do?

[[image]]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have already made some pegs in the feet and applied them somehow.  These pegs aren't really right....

[image]

Only the armature modifier is enabled, but we see that your feet contain cylinders with backwards normals, unconnected to the main mesh.

Elsewhere, we can see other problems with the mesh:

[image]

"Select non-manifold" operation shows me several problem areas, and we can see that there are other parts of the mesh with backwards normals-- that's where the face orientation shows as red instead of blue.

In order to work, booleans need to have a clear idea of what is inside of a mesh and what is outside of a mesh, so that they can calculate the intersection or difference between those volumes.  When meshes have non-manifold geometry, that's not well defined.

Additionally, it sounds as if your plan is to 3D print, and 3D printing also requires manifold meshes-- it needs just as clear a picture of what is supposed to be inside and what is supposed to be outside.

You need to do some work to clean up your mesh so that it is a single, manifold mesh.  Not just for purposes of the boolean, but for purposes of 3D printing as well.